# GMS Crash after firebase integration

Tags: firebase, google-play-services

My app keeps crashing giving this output

```
#0. Crashed: TubeSockReader-1: 0 0 0x0000000000000000
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpr.zzd(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpo.zzZM(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpo.zza(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpo$2.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)


Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toLowerCase(java.util.Locale)' on a null object reference
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpr.zzd(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpo.zzZM(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpo.zza(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpo$2.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

What could be the issue? I recently integrated the firebase realtime database and analytics.

Comment: We need a piece of code throws this error please

Comment: To be honest you could give much more information regarding this particular bit. Firebase is known for being barely debugable solely because of its obfuscated sources. For example, what are you using exactly in firebase? Is it messages, databases, etc.?